# Backtrack 5 On USB Error

Tags: linux, backtrack

I encounter that error when I shutdown or restart Backtrack5 on USB that I created boot from unetbootin !
That is the error :
(EE) FBDEV(0) : FBIOPUTCMAP : Invalid Arguement

The XKeyboard Keymap Compiler (XKBCOMP) Reports :

> Warning : Type"ONE_LEVEL" has 1 Levels but  has 2 Symbols
>
> ```
>     Ignoring Extra Symbols Errors from XKBCOMP are not Fatal to the XSERVER
> ```

BroadCast Message From root@root

(Unknown) At 15:02

The System is going down for reboot now !

Please Remove The Disc And Close The Tray ( If Any ) Then Press Enter :

---

After that all the information on the USB drive will be deleted !!!!!

How can I solve this problem ?

Can I install Backtrack 5 Completely on USB drive ?( I mean not boot it like cd )!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but you would need to use a live DVD to boot and select "Install Backtrack" on desktop. Then when choice for hard drive to install to comes up you select "Manually Select Partitions Advanced" and in that menu you will need to select your USB memory stick and partition it like you would a hard drive ( i.e. set a few hundred megs of space as SWAP and the rest format as EXT3 and mountpoint of / ). Also be sure to check "Advanced" tab and make sure bootloader is to be installed on your memory stick and not the MBR of your hard disk or you will screw up access to your current installs on your hard disk.